# 'Create New Project' in Android Studio is gone

Tags: android-studio-4.1

In Android Studio, there is no `Create New Project` option, only `Create New Flutter Project`,

I've already uninstalled and installed again Android Studio, but it's still like this:

[image: screenshot]

Can someone help me? How to get back the `Create New Project` option ?

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting Android Studio.
You can do it by deleting its user settings folder.

You will find it here:
C:\Users\Yourname.AndroidStudio

You can back up the data by saving or compress it in a zip file and then delete the folder contents. This will install to default.